# Git asks for password over ssh on One PC only

Tags: git

After updating from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04,I constantly get password prompt when interacting with company's self-hosted gitlab on my Desktop.
My other machine(laptop) connects through ssh perfectly.

I tried everything even replacing `.ssh` with the laptop. non of them work it still asks for password like it is a https and not an ssh connection.

Tried `ssh -T git@git.example.com` and it did work on laptop but asks for password on my desktop.

We use VPN for our internal services, I did tethered internet from laptop to desktop to use it's IP and check if the vpn is the problem, while I can connect to services this way but still have the same "git@git.example.com`s password:" prompt on my terminal.

Is there anyway to trace the problem? any cache to clear?

I can't simply use `https` remote urls cause I want to fetch `Go private modules` from the same git.

Comment: Is the private key on your laptop also on your desktop? (Note that you *shouldn't* be sharing private keys across machines, but generating a separate key pair for each machine and uploading *both* public keys to Gitlab.)

Comment: @chepner IKR, that's why I said "even".  I just wanted to equalize everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The RSA SHA-1 hash algorithm is being quickly deprecated. There is a workaround for re-enabling RSA at SSH-RSA key rejected with message "no mutual signature algorithm" .

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404049/ssh-without-password-does-not-work-after-upgrading-from-18-04-to-22-04/1404163#1404163

Although my problem was not the SHA-1 part as `ssh-keygen` seems to generate SHA-256 by default, but the other part of the answer above saved me anyway!

Add the following line to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client side:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: The problem is that your *server* is outdated, sending weak RSA keys to the *client*. Fix the server!

Comment: Yup, but can't do! Btw it's over vpn, so no one actually cares here... Neither I do have the access to do so.